# Let $T \in L(V)$ and $\{ v_{i} \}_{1\le i \le n } \in V$ such that $T(v_{1}),...,T(v_{n})$ generate $V$. Prove or disprove: $T$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This is the full question:

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$ and $T$ : $V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation, suppose that $v_{1},v_{2}....,v_{n}$ are vectors in $V$ such that $T(v_{1}),...,T(v_{n})$ generate $V$. Prove or disprove: $T$ is invertible.

I was not able to cook up any counter-examples for this statement(please make sure that $T$ satisfies the conditions of a Linear Transformation). The only information that we are given is the following,

> 1) Since  $T(v_{1}),...,T(v_{n})$ generate $V$. Then $\exists \,\, a_{1},a_{2},....,a_{n} \in F $ such that $$a_{1}T(v_{1})+a_{2}T(v_{2})+\cdots+a_{n}T(v_{n}) = v \hspace{5mm} \forall\,\, v \in V$$
>
> 2) Number of basis elements of $V$ are at most $n$

If we can show that $T$ maps the basis elements of $V$ to basis elements of $V$, then we are done. But i have no idea how to prove this from the given information.

Comment: 1) shows that $T$ is surjective. So what's its rank? Do you know the rank-nullity formula?

Comment: What the dimension of $V$? It depends wether if $dim V < n$ or viceversa

Comment: We just know that $V$ is finite dimensional.  So both these cases are possible.

Comment: I understood what you are trying to say @amsmath, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

$T$ is obviously onto. Suppose that $T$ is not one-to-one. If so, there exists $u \neq 0$ such that $T(u)=0$. Complement $u$ with $u_2, \dots u_n$ into a basis $(u, u_2, \dots,u_n)$. $T(V)$ is included into $Span(T(u_2), \dots, T(u_n))$ a linear subspace of $V$ of dimension $n-1$. Which is a contradiction with the hypothesis that $T(v_1), \dots, T(v_n)$ generates $V$.